# get password from /etc/shadow — awk vs Perl

Tags: perl, awk, passwords, shadow

I am wondering how to achieve this functionality in Perl

```
cat /etc/shadow | awk -F ":" '/root/{print $2}'
```

It would be nice to have your opinion what is better for this kind of task: Perl or awk.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "better". awk is standard on every UNIX box while perl is not and in some cases you're not allowed to install it or any other non-standard tools so that's one measure. Awk is a very small language designed to ONLY manipulate text while perl is a very large language designed to manipulate text and do everything a shell can do so awk is "better" if you're just manipulating text while perl is "better" if you're doing anything in addition to that. awk regexps are fast but perl regexps while slower have extra functionality so again "better" is in the eye of the beholder

Comment: For **this kind of task** awk is better as it's portable across all UNIX boxes plus (apparently from the answer you got) briefer, clearer (no-one draws images like http://geekshumor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/perl-scripts-done.png about awk syntax!) and probably faster than a perl equivalent.

Comment: Valid points, but 1) Few UNIX boxes lack Perl, the chances of eswues happening to be on such a box are well below 1%, 2) Perl syntax is as clear as you choose to make it 3) Perl has advantages over awk, e.g. it can do a lot more than text processing; but eswues may not need those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl has the switch `-F` to define a delimiter and turn on autosplitting into the array `@F`. Thus:

```
perl -F: -le 'print $F[1] if /root/' /etc/shadow     # Perl 5.20+
```

and

```
perl -anF: -le 'print $F[1] if /root/' /etc/shadow
```

will do the same as

```
awk -F: '/root/ {print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

I don't see a *real* difference between both.

Comment: [In Perl before v5.20](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html#%2A-F%2A-now-implies-%2A-a%2A-and-%2A-a%2A-implies-%2A-n%2A), that'll have to be `perl -anF: -e ...`

Comment: In Perl's after 5.8, you can trim that down a little with ``-E 'say $F[1] if …``

Comment: The main difference is when you find that your awk program cannot be enhanced to fulfil a new requirement. At that point it would have been much easier to have used Perl in the first place.

Comment: @Jim Davis, `-E` isn't forward compatible. You shouldn't use it in production. (And switching to `say` doesn't address the missing `chomp` like `-l` does.)